# Assumptions in Sum

Tags: summation, assumptions

I am calculating the following

```
Table[Sum[-((4 m^2)/(k + k^2 - l^2 - l)), {k, 1/2, Infinity},
  Assumptions -> {k \[Element] PositiveRationals, k != l}], {l, {1/2, 3/2, 5/2}}]
```

However all the sums diverge. It seems it is because `Sum` does not take into account the `Assumptions`: in fact if the limits of the `Sum` are, for example `{k, 3/2, Infinity}`, (so that the assumptions are satisfied for the first case) the first sum converges, while all the others diverge.

How do I make `Sum` consider the `Assumptions`?

Comment: `Assumptions` are not constraints, from the point of view of logic. You seem to want something like `Exclusions`, but I don't think `Assumptions` can be used to enforce exclusions. So the fact that `k == 1/2` in the sum contradicts the assumption `k != 1/2` does not mean `Assumptions` were ignored. That you don't get a `Sum::fas` message means maybe it did. OTOH, `Limit` ignores assumptions about the dummy variable; maybe `Sum` does, too. I don't think `Sum` is built to sum over arbitrary (discrete, ordered) sets. Best to "rephrase" the problem, imho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Table[
 Sum[If[k == l, 0, -((4 m^2)/(k + k^2 - l^2 - l))], {k, 1/2, 
   Infinity}],
 {l, {1/2, 3/2, 5/2}}]

(* {-3 m^2, -((3 m^2)/4), -(m^2/3)} *)
```

or

```
Table[
 Sum[Piecewise[{{-((4 m^2)/(k + k^2 - l^2 - l)), k != l}}], {k, 1/2, 
   Infinity}],
 {l, {1/2, 3/2, 5/2}}]

(* {-3 m^2, -((3 m^2)/4), -(m^2/3)} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you specify l==1/2  and sum over {k,1/2,..}, this is in opposition to your assumption: k!=l.

Further, If you sum 1/(k^2+k-l^2-l) starting from k==1/2 and set l==1/2 or 3/2 or 5/2, you will have a 1/zero term and no convergence.

However, if you sum starting with 7/2, to eliminate the divide by zero, all 3 series converge:

```
Table[Sum[-((4 m^2)/(k + k^2 - l^2 - l)), {k, 7/2, 
   Infinity}], {l, {1/2, 3/2, 5/2}}]

{-((7 m^2)/6), -((77 m^2)/60), -((49 m^2)/30)}
```

Comment: Yes I know... This is in fact written in my question... I imposed `l==1/2` just to show that the `Assumptions` are not taken into account in the `Sum`. So you are not answering the question.

Comment: If you play silly  tricks on the system, you can not expect to fullfill your wishes.